# Switching from MySQL to MSSQL for classic asp

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp-classic

Should it - in theory - be possible to just convert a mysql database to mssql **without any/with minimal code changes** in a classic asp website?

Comment: Your title and question are opposite each other. The title asks about MSSQL to MySQL, and the question asks about MySQL to MSSQL. You might want to fix that...

Comment: So sorry, the question was right...I'll amend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in theory you don't have to change much code.

What you do have to change?

1. All connection strings - if the code is well written the connection string is written once so just change it there otherwise search all code files for the old connection string and change it.
2. SQL delimeter: in `MySQL` it's the backtick character as far as I remeber and in SQL Server it's `[` and `]` characters - you need it to enclose table and field names which have space or are reserved words.
3. Special functions in SQL which are not standard.... no list, but keep watch for errors caused by such a difference.

Answer (score 2):

It depends completely on the SQL used.

If you have used functionality in one that doesn't exist (or is different) in the other, of course things have to be changed. For instance, if you're using CTEs in SQL Server, AFAIK they're not supported in MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, I got it the wrong way round in the title of the question.  This is probably true the other way round...can you think of anything in mysql that's not supported in mssql?

Answer (score 1):

one watch out for, as i've just spent the last couple of weeks doing a similar conversion is the zero datetime.

Since mySQL has a 'zero' datetime, `Convert Zero Datetime=true;` in the connection string,  and MSSQL doesnt, and if you've logic coded around this, you'll need to change it.